# 3D Weyl semimetals: lattice models

Tags: topological-insulators, graphene, lattice-model

Due to the graphene, honeycomb lattice is famous for host of 2D Dirac particles, with Hamiltonian:

$H = \sigma_x p_x + \sigma_y p_y$

where $\sigma_i$ are Pauli matrix.

Last few years, great interest in 3D Weyl semimetals, with Hamiltonian

$H = \sigma_x p_x + \sigma_y p_y + + \sigma_z p_z$

What lattices are host for 3D Weyl semimetals?

Especially, if system is without magnetic field or spin-orbit, is it possible to have 3D Weyl semimetal lattice model?

Comment: As far as I know, coupling together several layers of 2D lattices described by the QWZ model gives rise to 3D Weyl semimetal phases under some condition regarding the parameters of the model.